# Make android app better clickable

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an icon in my application and I made it clickable (When I click the icon, some action is called), but the problem is, you have to be really accurate. On the other hand the menu icon (the 3 dots) has a bigger "range" and when you click little bit outside, it is still working. Is there any way to achieve the same thing at the app icon? Or is there any better way to make a clickable icon in the upper left corner than using app icon?

Comment: yes, we do it by adding `padding` to the icon or button.

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding` to the icon, the more `padding` you add to it, the more clickable area you ll get!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a transparent button over your icon. Don't forget to make it unclickable and put enabled to false, so it doesn't intercepts the click intended for the icon.